# ASCII Art in c++ outputs wrong characters

Tags: c++, ascii

I am kinda new to coding and have run into a problem with my ASCII art that I am trying to add onto my project. I think that the problem is because of the character set or strings. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << R"(
 ███████████ ████  ██████████ ███████████  
░█░░░███░░░█░░███ ░░███░░░░░█░░███░░░░░███ 
░   ░███  ░  ░███  ░███  █ ░  ░███    ░███ 
    ░███     ░███  ░██████    ░██████████  
    ░███     ░███  ░███░░█    ░███░░░░░███ 
    ░███     ░███  ░███ ░   █ ░███    ░███ 
    █████    █████ ██████████ █████   █████
   ░░░░░    ░░░░░ ░░░░░░░░░░ ░░░░░   ░░░░░ 
                                           
                                           
                                               
)" << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

I want it to output it with looking like this:

[image: Picture of what it should look like]

But what it outputs is this error: [image: Error message]

to which I click "no"
and then get this in the console:

[image: Console output]

If someone knows what it happening please help.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Can you [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text? All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You'll find many other questions here, with a [mre], in plain text. Please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: There is no difference in the text when pressing "yes", I will edit the post now.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to create ASCII art but using characters which are not part of ASCII.

Comment: I have set it to use multi-byte character set

Comment: @Isak Setting a multi-byte character set effects the way that the Windows API works, it has no effect on standard C++ which is what you are using.

Comment: @john Okay, but how can I make the console show the correct characters?

Comment: @Isak this question gets asked a lot, I'll see if I can find a duplicate. IIRC it's not a particularly easy thing to do however.

Comment: You selected that you do not want to maintain your data. The IDE probably saved question marks in the file for the non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @user253751 I have also tried pressing yes on the popup, but it still didn't work

Comment: @Isak Wasn't able to find a good duplicate (maybe you'll have more luck searching). But note there are two parts to this problem and you have to solve both of them. The first part is that you have to encode your string literals correctly. Apparently you'll have more luck if you use wide strings and use UTF-16 for the encoding but YMMV. The second point is that you have to get the console to correctly display whatever encoding you choose. This might involve some use of the Windows API.

Comment: @Isak I'm afraid that almost always when these kind of questions are asked, they are asked by programmers who have no knowledge of the underlying issues (encodings, character sets etc). If that's you then spending some time learning these about subjects would be the first thing to do.

Comment: Ill look more into it, thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: It works for Ubuntu/g++. Therefore, I guess it is compiler issue.

Comment: As the very first thing in `main`, does `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8");` help (as per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page))?  Assuming Windows 10 build 17134 (April 2018 Update) or later, the Universal C Runtime supports using a UTF-8 code page.  And assuming your source file is saved in UTF-8 format (aka code page 65001).

Comment: @Eljay It does not work.

Comment: @Isak -- How did you enter those characters into the source code?  From the keyboard?  As others mentioned, if you want to deal with non-ASCII characters, there are multiple moving parts to get right -- it isn't just a simple copy/paste from your favorite app into the source code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I copy pasted it.

Comment: @Isak -- In general, you should be careful when copying and pasting from anything other than a generic text editor.  I have seen other issues copying and pasting from applications, where quotes are not ASCII quotes, hyphens are not ASCII hyphens, etc.

Comment: Drat.  Sorry Isak.  My Windows computer is down right now (*the magic blue smoke got out*, **:sad panda:**), so I can't futz around to see if I can make it work.  Hopefully's gotanod's answer works for you.

Comment: Windows natively represents unicode as wide characters (i.e 16 bits), check out  [working with strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

std::wcout instead of std::cout, and add u8 literal identifier.
It works for me only adding the **u8** literal.

```
 std::wcout << u8R"(
 ███████████ ████  ██████████ ███████████  
░█░░░███░░░█░░███ ░░███░░░░░█░░███░░░░░███ 
░   ░███  ░  ░███  ░███  █ ░  ░███    ░███ 
    ░███     ░███  ░██████    ░██████████  
    ░███     ░███  ░███░░█    ░███░░░░░███ 
    ░███     ░███  ░███ ░   █ ░███    ░███ 
    █████    █████ ██████████ █████   █████
   ░░░░░    ░░░░░ ░░░░░░░░░░ ░░░░░   ░░░░░ 
                                           
                                           
                                               
)" << '\n';
```

[UTF-8 literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-170)

[std::wcout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)